# How do I get the content-type from return of urlopen(url) in python2.x?

Tags: python

Are theere any functions in 3.x using the http.client.HTTPMessage().get_content_type() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`urllib2.urlopen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) returns an `addinfourl` with `headers`:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
>>> f.headers['content-type']
'text/html'
>>>
```